# mysql- pivot filas a columnas

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

tengo una base de datos donde tengo la siguiente tabla:

| idservicio | idcliente | nombre contacto | telefono |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76543 | 2 | maria perez | 123456 |
| 76543 | 2 | miguel o | 765433 |
| 98765 | 1 | sara perez | 876658 |
| 98765 | 1 | jose o | 987665 |
| 98765 | 1 | orlando | 876540 |
| 76543 | 3 | jack | 123456 |
| 76543 | 3 | ana | 654324 |
| 76543 | 3 | kevin | 954326 |

y quiero hacer una consulta donde la salida sea de la siguiente forma:

| idservicio | idcliente | telefono 1 | telefono 2 | telefono 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76543 | 2 | 123456 | 765433 |  |
| 98765 | 1 | 876658 | 987665 | 876540 |
| 76543 | 3 | 123456 | 654324 | 954326 |

En SQL server lo hacia con row_number over partition by , como puedo hacerlo en mysql ,, tengo la version 5.7.36

Comment: De entre [las preguntas del sitio](/search?q=pivot+[mysql]+[pivot]), ¿has encontrado algo que se asemeje a tu pregunta? Por cierto, elimina la etiqueta _mysql-workbench_, ya que es irrelevante aquí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues la pregunta tiene su miga, no es el típico pivotaje... Yo lo he resuelto así:

```
SELECT idservicio,idcliente,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(telefonos,',',1) telefono_1,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTR(telefonos,LOCATE(',',telefonos)+1),',',1
  ) telefono_2,
  REPLACE(SUBSTR(
    telefonos,LOCATE(',',telefonos,12)
  ),',','') telefono_3
  FROM (
    SELECT idservicio,idcliente,
      GROUP_CONCAT(telefono) telefonos
      FROM telefonos
      GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c1;
```

Obteniendo este resultado:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
| idservicio | idcliente | telefono_1 | telefono_2 | telefono_3 |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|      76543 |         2 | 123456     | 765433     |            |
|      76543 |         3 | 123456     | 654324     | 954326     |
|      98765 |         1 | 876658     | 987665     | 876540     |
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Para este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE telefonos(
  idservicio int,
  idcliente int,
  nombre_contacto varchar(31),
  telefono varchar(11)
  );

INSERT INTO telefonos (idservicio, idcliente, nombre_contacto, telefono) VALUES
('76543','2','maria perez','123456'),
('76543','2','miguel o','765433'),
('98765','1','sara perez','876658'),
('98765','1','jose o','987665'),
('98765','1','orlando','876540'),
('76543','3','jack','123456'),
('76543','3','ana','654324'),
('76543','3','kevin','954326');
```

Comment: El problema de esta consulta es que está restringido a 3 teléfonos. Si por ejemplo hacemos un `INSERT INTO telefonos (idservicio, idcliente, nombre_contacto, telefono) VALUES ('123456',3,'luis','777777') no podríamos ver el 4º teléfono

Comment: @VFG ¿Y se te ocurre cómo generalizarlo a n teléfonos? En PHP serviría un simple `explode()` pero, en MySQL, ni idea... :(